# Migration from one Macbook to another

Tags: macbook-pro, time-capsule, migration

I am going to buy new Macbook and want to transfer all my programs and data to it.  I have googled and as I see the Migration Assistant the best way to do it.  Is it right ?

If it is, I have additional questions:

1. What is the best way to transfer:  from old Macbook or from Time Capsule ?
2. My old Macbook have OS X 10.10 installed.  The new one will have 10.9 version.  Can I use Migration Assistant in this case or it will be better to upgrade the new Macbook to 10.10 firstly ?

Comment: Because 10.10 (Yosemite) is still in beta, there might be unintended and unexpected consequences using MA to migrate to a 10.9 installation. On the other hand, it may work flawlessly.

Answer (score 2):

The Migration Assistant was made by Apple for one purpose only, so it is the best way to migrate from one device to another.

As for the 10.10 since it is still in beta phases, the Migration Assistant on the host computer might not work as it should, since beta phase testing is not completed yet.

Since 10.10 has it own way of managing the files ect... the transfer to 10.9 might have problems with that.

[10.10 Release notes:](http://fairerplatform.com/2014/06/can-mac-run-os-x-10-10-yosemite/)

OS X 10.10 Installation
Known Issues
Migration Assistant may hang while transferring your information from a Time Machine backup. To proceed with the login, quit the Installer.